# How to get such data as abstraction, location and link for image in Dbpedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to get some data about museum but it is not successfull. This is my code. I know the name of the museum, so I want to get data about this museum

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT ?abstract ?location WHERE {
?architectural_structure rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Museum .
?architectural_structure dbpedia-owl:location dbpedia:Taganrog .
?architectural_structure dbpprop:name dbpedia:Chekhov_Shop .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dbpprop:name` that you have selected (`dbpedia:Chekhov_Shop`) is in fact a string. If you look at the dbpedia page it has been defined as `The Chekhov Shop`. Therefore, my suggestion is to filter your query based on the name you like to be displayed:

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?architectural_structure rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Museum .
    ?architectural_structure dbpedia-owl:location dbpedia:Taganrog .
    ?architectural_structure dbpprop:name ?name.
Filter (str(?name)="The Chekhov Shop")
}
```

And if you need more information about this specific architectural structure, you start exploring. For example,

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT distinct * WHERE {
    ?architectural_structure rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Museum .
    ?architectural_structure dbpedia-owl:location dbpedia:Taganrog .
    ?architectural_structure dbpprop:name ?name.
    ?architectural_structure dbpprop:location ?location.
    ?architectural_structure dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
Filter (str(?name)="The Chekhov Shop")
}
```

In general, when you are faced with a triple store try to find all `?o ?p ?s` and then see where you need to put a specific predicate.